# Module Disappears from Project Explorer of IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, workspace

I am using IntelliJ for working on Java Modules of my app. However, one of the modules is disappearing form the Project explorer randomly. This module was not originally added to the Project Explorer when this workspace was created.

Do I need to explicitly save some settings or do I need to save the work-space in a specific way such that it doesn't disappear?

FYI,
How am I adding a project in my work-space:
**Go to "Project Structure" -> Alt + Insert -> Import Module -> Select .iml file of my module -> Click on "Ok"**

The Project is now visible in Project->Packages on left hand side navigation view. But after may be an IntelliJ restart, it will be gone and I'll have to import again to see its files.

*Note : I understand that the question could be quite on a broader context, but as a new developer on IntelliJ platform, I am looking for a setting change which can fix this. I believe the project or code has nothing to do with it. However, I can certainly be wrong, but my intent is to only understand if this is some customizable behavior of IntelliJ.*

Comment: Hi Jim, I have rephrased the question. Hope it helps now.

Comment: @Dish Is your main project Gradle or Maven based? Can you share [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide the exact steps to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder : My main project is maven based. I have mentioned the steps I have used to import a project in the question. It is an intermittent issue, I dont know what causes the project to disappear. Sadly, I havent been able to find a pattern. Never mind, thanks for your question.

Comment: @Dish module reference is stored in `.idea/modules.xml` file in the project root. Make sure this file is not modified/reverted externally. Check the file diff. If you are using some VCS and adding the module manually, you have to store this file in the version control.

Comment: @CrazyCoder : Inside .idea folder I only have misc.xml, vcs.xml and workspace.xml - in none of these files I could find any of the existing module names. The content of the file is quite generic.

Comment: @Dish You may have [this option enabled](https://i.imgur.com/lmnmF53.png). Try to disable it, reimport the project, then add a module and see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that I was checking at the wrong places for the fix. The actual culprit was here:

**Project -> Settings -> Maven -> Ignored Files**

The `pom.xml` file of the Project that was disappearing was marked as ignored here. That's why I was having to import the module every time I would restart IntelliJ. But post the restart, the module was being removed considering it is to be ignored.

**Uncheck the pom.xml from above setting.**

---

EDIT

---

Apart from above fix make sure your modules are loaded in IDEA IntelliJ.
Right click on **Project View -> Load/Unload Modules.. -> Verify that the module is among loaded ones.**

Comment: Great! I ran into this problem recently. My modules disappeared after a machine restart. "Load/Unload..." showed that the modules were already loaded but the Project View did not reflect that. I had to "Unload All" then "Load All" to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well so now come to point
I had the same issue and applied many available solutions but couldn't resolve my issue.

1. Delete all copy of your projects
2. Clone fresh project in Intellij follow below steps:

A. Open IntelliJ
B. Remove all the linked projects if you have
C. Click on projects in left side
D. Now click on Get from VCS and paste your clone/bitbucket URL in it

[Intellij IDEA Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuGu8.png)